# How to clean up data in R using strings?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, stringr

I need to clean up gender and dates columns of the dataset found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kDoLxk9BkPs34aSyY1GwOkYj3unUjJIZ/view?usp=sharing).

They apparently contain some misspellings and ambiguities. I am new to R and data cleaning so I am not sure how to go about doing this. For starters, I have tried to correct the misspellings using

```
factor(data$artist_data$gender)
str_replace_all(data$artist_data$gender, pattern = "femle", replacement = "Female")
str_replace_all(data$artist_data$gender, pattern = "f.", replacement = "Female")
str_replace_all(data$artist_data$gender, pattern = "F.", replacement = "Female")
str_replace_all(data$artist_data$gender, pattern = "female", replacement = "Female")
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I still have `f.`, `F.` and `femle` in my output. Secondly, there seem to be empty cells inside. Do I need to remove them or is it alright to leave them there. If I need to remove them, how?

Thirdly, for the dates column, how do I make it clearer? i.e. change the format of `born in xxxx` to maybe `xxxx-yyyy` if died or `xxxx-present` if still alive. e.g. `born in 1940` - is it safe to assume that they are still alive? Also one of the data has the word active in it. Would like to make this data more straight-forward.

Please help,
Thank you.

Comment: edit: I have to use stringr

Comment: The input is missing.  No one can run your code except you.   Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Do you capture the results back into `data$artist_data$gender`? These function (and most of R) do not work inside-effect, they do not change the data in-place. You need to do something like `data$artist_data$gender <- str_replace_all(data$artist_data$gender, ...)` to capture the change.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that. Originally when I ran factor(data$artist_data$gender) before cleaning, I got f. F. female Female femle Male.

After I excuted the codes as you mentioned, factor(data$artist_data$gender) became Levels:  Female Femalemale Femalemalemale Femalemalemle Male

Answer (score 1):

We have to escape the dot in f. and F.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)

pattern <- paste("f\\.|F\\.|female|femle", collapse="|")

df[[2]] %>% 
  mutate(gender = str_replace(string=gender,
                                  pattern = pattern,
                                  replacement="Female")) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

```
   name                   gender dates     placeOfBirth                   placeOfDeath            
   <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>                          <chr>                   
 1 Abakanowicz, Magdalena Female born 1930 Polska                         ""                      
 2 Abbey, Edwin Austin    Male   1852–1911 Philadelphia, United States    "London, United Kingdom"
 3 Abbott, Berenice       Female 1898–1991 Springfield, United States     "Monson, United States" 
 4 Abbott, Lemuel Francis Male   1760–1803 Leicestershire, United Kingdom "London, United Kingdom"
 5 Abrahams, Ivor         Male   born 1935 Wigan, United Kingdom          ""                      
 6 Absalon                Male   1964–1993 Tel Aviv-Yafo, Yisra'el        "Paris, France"         
 7 Abts, Tomma            Female born 1967 Kiel, Deutschland              ""                      
 8 Acconci, Vito          Male   born 1940 New York, United States        ""                      
 9 Ackling, Roger         Male   1947–2014 Isleworth, United Kingdom      ""                      
10 Ackroyd, Norman        Male   born 1938 Leeds, United Kingdom          ""                      
# ... with 3,522 more rows
```

Comment: Hi, I am only allowed to use stringr library. I tried using apply(data$artist_data$gender, pattern, str_replace_all) but received an error saying dim(X) must have a positive length